# Spacebar shortcut for JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm working on a menu-driven java swing application. It has 4 to 5 menus have 4 or more menu items. I defined shortcuts for all the menu item using `JMenuBar#setKeyAccelerator(KeyStroke key)`. But When I define `spacebar` as a shortcut and then press `space`, it fires event for my first `JMenuItem` or previously selected menu item. Here is my code snippet:

```
JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("Do Something");
item.setKeyAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0));
```

How to add spacebar to the menuitem so that it works fine.

Comment: The `setKeyAccelerator(...)` method hasn't existed for a long time know. I would suggest you get a more current JDK. Any I tested using VK_SPACE on a current JDK and it works fine. I just downloaded the `MenuLookDemo.java` code from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) and changed one of the accelerators. If it doesn't work for you, then maybe you have multiple menu items using space as the accelerator or maybe it is a JDK problem. Can't tell based on two lines of code.

Comment: @camickr I'm using Java version 7 update 45.

Comment: Well, like I said, look at the tutorial for working examples. We can't help you based on two lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spot my problem, I added a toolbar having a button and my button is automatically focused, that's why when I press space, it press my button on JToolBar